Touch function disturbance after installing screen protector
I have a strange problem with my Samsung Galaxy A14 phone, as soon as I install a screen protector for the device, a problem occurs in the touch function, which is: when touching a point on the upper half of the screen and waiting six seconds or more, the entire upper section becomes unresponsive to touch until a point on the lower half of the screen is touched!

I have changed the screen protector three times to no avail.
No problem occurs if the screen protector is removed.
This problem does not occur when the charger is connected to the device even with the screen protector installed .
What is the explanation for this and what is the solution?


Does this happen only on home screen or other screens/app drawer? Some devices have a touchscreen sensitivity setting (screen protector mode in Pixel) in accessibility settings. Did you go through all the settings to find some such?

Was your device dropped or subjected to some harsh treatment recently (accidentally, of course)?

I tried increase touchscreen sensitivity  from settings menue and it does not work !

No ,  the phone did not dropp , No physical thing happened !
